# Unable to set the cookie using HttpWebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

i have following code for login to `POST http://www.160by2.com/logincheck.aspx?iamindian=` this url, my problem is m not able to login and when i debug it using Fiddler, i can't see ne cookie thought i'm using `CookieContainer` class, here m using windows app in c#

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.160by2.com/logincheck.aspx?iamindian=");
        string PostData = string.Format("htxt_UserName={0}&txt_Passwd={1}&txt_pop=&s=&d=&cmdSubmit=&namenumber={2}&strclf=&strshareuser=&ucountry=&ucode=&ucity=&uregion=", txtMobile.Text, txtPassword.Text, "1");
        CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Referer = "http://www.160by2.com";
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sWriter.Write(PostData);
        sWriter.Close();

        request.GetResponse().Close();
        //some more code is here for further posting but above code can't login so below code is also not working
```

i followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248672/httpwebrequest-and-set-cookie-header-in-response-not-parsed-wp7), post but it didn't help'd me..
   Please, Help me out here where m goin' wrong..

Answer (score 5):

Thats really true, because

```
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
```

you have put nothing to your cookie container.

Use Add method, to put actual values to cookie

```
container.Add(new Uri("http://yoursite"), new Cookie("name", "value"));
```

and do post again.

Comment: i'm sry that m askin' this stupid question, i'm geting cookie value as `Cookie: name=value` in fiddler, what shld i pass for `name and value` in `new Cookie("name","value")`..

Comment: and i didn't get you, what you mean by `Use Add method, to put actual values to cookie` coz, i dn't know what to set in the cookie, here i'm posting login credential to that URI in return it sends cookie which is to be set..

Comment: i was following this tutorials http://odetocode.com/Articles/162.aspx
as per this, that guy is also not setting nething to the cookie container, m totally confused..

Comment: @FosterZ: it depends on app, if http://www.160by2.com/logincheck.aspx recieves data from cookie, you should pass some.. it would be better if you provide with exact scenario you need

Comment: i have chk'd it in fiddler, as far i know it is not recieving ne data from cookie, my scenario is just i want to login to this site using HttpWebRequest,

Answer (score -2):

this is working properly try it

```
Cookie objCookie = new Cookie("data", "Scott");
    cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(txtURL.Text), objCookie);
```