# Windows phone 7 - How to use HTTPWebRequest to POST / GET data from a .jsp site[with cookies]

Tags: windows-phone-7

Title sums it up fairly well.

Said site has cookies, I need to post data from a textbox as a value on said site, and get one of two variables back. I was reading through some tutorials and a few Windows phone 7 books. None of them were related to what I was trying to do. They only dealt with single whole files or something that could be made into a URL. I could also do it that way if someone had a way to also use cookies and just send it as a url [but i do not know how to construct the url in such a way to make that a realistic solution].

Comment: Not sure what you mean and what cookies have to do with this. Variables are usually sent in the query string as a get request or a dictionary formed of post requests. Perhaps posting some code including the server side will help

Comment: @Lee  The site just has to be able to place a cookie, I'm sure I can just use a container as stated below. The site I don't want to have to redo, so it's just a bunch of javascript textboxes and a button. I just don't know how to send post / get using the same variables used on the site. Not sure if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to send cookie's using code like:

```
CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
container.Add(new Uri("http://yoursite"), new Cookie("name", "value"));
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://yoursite");
request.CookieContainer = container;
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetData), request);
```

Code borrowed from [HttpWebRequest and Set-Cookie header in response not parsed (WP7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248672/httpwebrequest-and-set-cookie-header-in-response-not-parsed-wp7)

If the server is expecting to use cookies (e.g. for authentication) then there is no way that you'll be able to use form variables/query parameters instead.

You need to use a tool called [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the calls that the website currently makes - this will include a mixture of:

- cookie variables - especially for authentication
- get variables - passed within the url path
- and post variables - passed within the body of the request

If you do need to do a full POST, then you will need to set variables like - request.Method and request.ContentType - and you will need to brovide a RequestStream. There are libraries you can use like HAMMOCK to help - or I've got some example code in [iron7](http://www.wp7comp.com/iron7) - see the DoCodePost method at the botom of [this uploader class](https://github.com/slodge/main/blob/master/Hosts/Silverlight/Iron7/Utils/ScriptUploader.cs) - or take a look at lots of other projects on CodePlex and GitHub.

Comment: Yes but there are javascript variables that i need to post / get, not sure how that would work out within the web request function, or i guess the formatting [since it all seems to be url based in the end].

Comment: Have provided some more info for you - best advice is to use Fiddler to understand what the protocol is - if you are using cookies and POSTs then it is not all url based in the end - cookies are sent in the HTTP headers and POST data is sent in the request body. Hope that helps