# Reading HttpOnly Cookies from Headers of HttpWebResponse in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Is there any way to read HttpOnly Cookies from Headers of HttpWebResponse in Windows Phone?

In my code below **"Set-Cookie"** is not present in **response.Cookies[]**

My code

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the get response operation
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
        {
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

            // But Set-Cookie is not present here as its HttpOnly
            var cookies = response.Cookies["Set-Cookie"];

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
            {
                String Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();

                // Call the response callback
                if (Callback != null)
                {
                    Callback(this, new EventArgs1() { Response = Response, Cookie = cookies });
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot access HttpOnly cookies directly.
You can pass them to different requests using a CookieContainer, but you cannot read them.

```
CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequest();

request.CookieContainer = container;

//do some requests
```